# How to install msi pkg on windows using salt-stack?

Tags: linux, salt-stack

I want to install msi pkg on windows server using salt-stack.

I have tried the msi pkg installation on windows server as per given in documentation but its not working.
can any one suggest ?

Comment: Show us what exactly did you try and what error you got.

Comment: [DEBUG   ] Loaded minion key: c:\salt\conf\pki\minion\minion.pem
[DEBUG   ] Fetching file ** attempting ** 'salt://win/repo/winrepo.p'
[ERROR   ] Unable to cache file "salt://win/repo/winrepo.p" from env "base".
[ERROR   ] Not able to read repo file
[ERROR   ] [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: ''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "salt/modules/win_pkg.py", line 701, in get_repo_data
  File "salt/utils/__init__.py", line 903, in fopen
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: ''
[DEBUG   ] Initializing COM library

Comment: this is the error which i get it on windows server 2008 minion

Comment: salt minion1 pkg.refresh_db                                            [INFO    ] User root Executing command pkg.refresh_db with jid 2015010511350643
460
[DEBUG   ] Command details {'tgt_type': 'glob', 'jid': '20150105113506436460',
tgt': 'NVMBD1CDV230V01', 'ret': '', 'user': 'root', 'arg': [], 'fun': 'pkg.refr
sh_db'}
[DEBUG   ] Parsed args: []
[DEBUG   ] Parsed kwargs: {}
[DEBUG   ] Fetching file ** attempting ** 'salt://win/repo/winrepo.p'
[ERROR   ] Unable to cache file "salt://win/repo/winrepo.p" from env "base".
[INFO    ] Returning information for job: 20150105113506436460

Comment: have you run salt-run winrepo.genrepo on the master? If so what is the result?